# Trigger Preventing Record Insertion

Tags: mysql, triggers, eventtrigger

I was trying to create trigger which can update value of column user_count of table user_details using value of u_count of table user_info.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test` 
AFTER INSERT ON `user_details` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE default_user_count int(11); 
   SELECT u_count INTO @default_user_count FROM 
   user_info WHERE user_info.id= user_details.id_c; 
   IF user_details.user_count= 0 
       THEN UPDATE user_details SET 
       user_count = default_user_count 
       WHERE user_details.id_c = user_info.id; 
  END IF; 
END
```

Trigger saved successfully but when i tried to insert value in both table it is preventing to insert record into user_details means no row inserted in 2 this table, if we delete trigger then its working.

Can anyone let me know wrong with this trigger?

THanks,
M.

Comment: You are not allowed to modify the contents of a table in a trigger on that table.

Comment: It's fairly apparent what's wrong with the trigger... but it's really hard to understand what you're actually trying to do, and why... If the data exists in one table, you should typically fetch it when you need it (later) with a join... not by copying it.

Comment: @Michael: I dont have access to core files so i can not make changes inside code. Thats why i was trying to create trigger ON AFTER INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems like it's something like what we have below.

There are numerous errors in and ambiguities in your trigger.

- Confusion on variables -- `DECLARE default_user_count INT(11);` *does not* declare the user-defined variable `@default_user_count`.  It declares the program variable `default_user_count`.  The `@` prefix references an entirely different variable scope and namespace.
- `SELECT` and `UPDATE` from the table which invoked the trigger doesn't usually make sense (`SELECT`) or is completely invalid (`UPDATE`).
- With in a trigger, you are operating `FOR EACH ROW` -- that is, for each row included in the statement that invoked the trigger.  Inside an `INSERT` trigger, the `NEW` values for the row are in a pseudo-table/pseudo-row accessible via the alias `NEW`.  For `UPDATE` triggers, there are `NEW` and `OLD` row values, and for `DELETE` triggers, just `OLD`.
- `AFTER INSERT` doesn't seem to make sense.  I think you're looking for `BEFORE INSERT` -- that is, while processing an `INSERT INTO ...` query, *before* the newly-inserted row actually gets written into the table, modify its values accordingly.  The resulting row contains the original values except where the trigger has modified them.
- `SELECT ... INTO` a variable is a practice you should not get into the habit of, because [it can bite you in a way a scalar subquery can't](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651), by leaving a variable unexpectedly unaltered instead of setting it to `NULL` as would be expected.  In this case, it would have made no difference, but it's still a caution worth mentioning... and in this case, I've eliminated that intermediate variable altogether, so the subquery is the only option.

If you are trying to set a value in this table using a value found in another table, all you need to do is `SET NEW.column_name` equal to the value you want used in the row instead of the value provided with the insert statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `user_details` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   IF NEW.user_count = 0 /* maybe also >> */ OR NEW.user_count IS NULL /* << this */ THEN
     SET NEW.user_count = (SELECT ui.u_count 
                             FROM user_info ui
                            WHERE ui.id = NEW.id_c);
   END IF;
END
```

Again, it's unclear how the two tables are connected based on the content of the original question, but this appears to do what you're trying to accomplish.